# Listing service operations alphabetically in WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe)

Tags: wcf, wcftestclient

I often use WCF Test Client. Unfortunately this tool does not order alphabetically nor in "order of appearance" (order in which operations are declared in service contract class). This make it quite difficult to find specific operation if there are many.

Is there any way to force WCF Test Client, to order the operations alphabetically? 
Where the default ordering comes from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though it does not seem to be possible to order operations alphabetically I realized that WCF Test Client has built-in incremental search.

That helps if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  For those looking for the "Search menu" in the test client, you get this psuedo functionality by clicking on the list of operations and then hitting the keyboard letter that begins the operation (repeatedly will iterate through the operations starting with the letter) one can get a search like functionality it seems.