# WCF Test Client - Sort service functions by name

Tags: web-services, wcftestclient

When I add a service reference in WCF Test Client all of the exposed service functions are listed but in no order I could figure out...

Is there a way to sort the exposed service functions alphabetically?

Weather in WCF Test Client or in the service itself?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to not be possible.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29470615/456167), WCFTestClient will take the same order as the `Type.GetMethods` method which follows no particular order.

But as pointed out in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916677/456167), you can just type the first letters of the name of the method to highlight it (I agree this is not what we really want!)